# Upload media to WordPress shows gray document icon instead of thumbnail and doesn't get uploaded to FTP

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, upload

I am having trouble uploading images to my new WordPress installation. I can upload without errors, but am not able to see the image thumbnail. I only see a gray document icon instead (not a broken image). It has the correct upload path, but when I search for the file on my FTP I can only see an empty uploads folder, which means wordpress is not uploading anything. If I change the uploads folder on the wp-settings.php and try uploading media again, it actualy creates the path on the FTP, but it doesn't show any media inside.

I tried changing the premissions for the wp-contents folder and all its subdirectories, I even set them to 777 but didn't work.

I also deactivated all the plugins.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question right now - even if I hope you solved this in the meantime, you should check _posts and _postmeta table and verifying that id columns have autoincrement in them.